# Hedge fund database with daily data

Tags: data, historical-data

I am looking for a hedge fund database that provides returns daily. Is there any data provider that gives daily data?

Answer (score 3):

Most hedges funds only allow monthly subscriptions and redemptions; which means they will only publish official prices on a monthly basis.

If someone does publish daily data view it with suspicion.

Having said that [HFRX](https://www.hedgefundresearch.com) publish numbers on a daily basis.

Answer (score 1):

I used to use a source called [HedgeFundnet](https://www.evestment.com/about/acquisitions/hedgefund-net), which was acquired by Evestment in 2011.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about daily data, but you could have a peek at [barclayhedge](http://www.barclayhedge.com)

Answer (score 1):

[NilssonHedge.com](https://www.nilssonhedge.com) offers access to daily return data. Full disclosure, I am the owner of the site.